# ssh -D to my server

Tags: ssh

I want to route my `localhost:1500` to my server in US, 
my command is:

```
ssh -D 1500 192.241.79.124
password : ...
```

but this error appears :

```
cannot listen to port 1500
could not request local forwarding
```

what would I do?

Comment: Find out what's already listening on port 1500.

Comment: how would i do that? sorry , i'm not expert on centos

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible issues here:

1. Something may already be listening on port 1500
2. Port forwarding may be disallowed in the SSHD config on the target server

To find out if something is already listening on port 1500, run the following command:

```
jenny@scorpio:~> netstat -na | grep 1500
```

If something is listening, you should get output looking something like

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1500              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If nothing is listening, you need to talk to whoever is in charge of the target machine to check whether `AllowTcpForwarding` is set to  `No`, and, if so, whether they are willing to change that.